# How to "double pop"?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I'm sorry if my title is a bit unclear, I wasn't sure how to express my problem better. I will give a quick code snippet to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
for data_file in data_files:
    analyze(data_file)

def analyze(data_file):
    for _ in np.arange(n_steps):
        foo(data_file)
    do some other things

def foo(data_file):
    do some things
    if (value > 1): 
        do some things
        double_return()
    else:
        continue doing other things
```

What I want the function `double_return()` to do then, is to return back to the larger loop:

```
for data_file in data_files:
```

(Instead of `return`, which would continue to the next step in `for _ in n_steps`). However, I am not sure what command to use here and haven't been able to find it.

Comment: The terminology you're looking for is either "`return`" or "`break`", not "pop".

Comment: @mtraceur: ... although thinking about it in machine language terms you could do a double `pop` of the program stack.

Comment: You could just check the return value from foo, or define a custom exception.

Comment: @quamrana yeah, not even just machine code - at all levels of abstraction, whether machine code, Python bytecode, or Python source - if it has a call stack, you can reasonably apply the word "pop" to it. But that's piercing the most relevant high-level abstraction (return), and using "pop" in the question title makes many Python devs think of stuff like `dict.pop`, and many devs in general think of regular/general stacks.

Comment: @quamrana P.S. btw machine code doesn't inherently require a call stack (for example, you can implement everything with continuation passing and monads instead of a call stack - the call stack just happens to be a decent design choice which is simple to implement and decently good at expressing many programs).

Comment: It's just that, of the limited number of CPUs that I've programmed in machine code, everyone has a stack pointer which can be manually popped etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo()` could return `True`, if it completes, or `False` if you want to “leave early”:

```
for data_file in data_files:
   analyze(data_file)

def analyze(data_file):
   for _ in np.arange(n_steps):
       if not foo(data_file):
          return
   do some other things

def foo(data_file):
   do some things
   if (value > 1):
       do some things
       return False
   else:
       continue doing other things

   return True
```

**Edit:** 
To make the meaning clearer, you could define `foo_completed=True`, and `foo_not_completed=False`, and use these constants instead of True/False.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to return a `truthy` value (assuming all the other routes out of `foo()` are the default `return None`) and test for it:

```py
def analyze(data_file):
    for _ in np.arange(n_steps):
        if foo(data_file):
            return
    do some other things

def foo(data_file):
    do some things
    if (value > 1): 
        do some things
        return True
    else:
        continue doing other things

for data_file in data_files:
    analyze(data_file)
```

It rather obscures the meaning, but it will work in a testable way.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand correctly, the None will be interpreted as 'False' in the if statement?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There are `Truthy` and `Falsy` values in python as mentioned in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false). I added `return True` as the smallest change to your code assuming that all other routes out of `foo()` just return `None` by default.